# Optimization tools for C and C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, optimization, gcc

What tools for Windows and Linux systems can I use to determine alignment issues, cache misses and other parameters relevant to code generated by Visual C++ and GCC? Can I use these tools to determine the alignment of structures so I can avoid compiler-generated padding?

Comment: Automatic padding is there to eliminate alignment issues...

Comment: On Stack Overflow your questions should be phrased as questions and not as commands, or you'll put off lots of potential answerers. I've edited your post to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine cache misses you'll want a CPU-level profiler, like `oprofile` or `vtune`, or a dynamic instrumentation tool, like `valgrind` with `cachegrind`.

To look for alignment issues on structures, there is a tool called `pahole` for object files with `DWARF` debugging information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a tool for windows similar to pahole? BTW, can you elaborate or point tutorials on enabling cache parameters in vtune / kcachegrind?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid padding in data structures you could using `__attribute__((__packed__))` for gcc or for microsoft visual studio `#pragma(pack(push,1))` before the declaration of your structure an `#pragma(pop)` after the declaration of your structure. 
You could also give the command line option to microsoft visual studio compiler /Zp1 for packing at one byte http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0(v=vs.80).aspx or with gcc -falign-function=8 for packing at 1 byte boundaries. Your code base would be smaller however this could have serious negative effects on your performance...

Comment: Not only performance. If you have a struct { char, int } the int wouldn't be correctly aligned any longer, which would mean it would no longer be updated atomically..